# Riemannian norm with respect to the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, vector-fields

Let M be a Riemannian manifold $p\in M$, $X,Y\in T_pM$. I am given the variation $v(s,t)=exp_p(t(X+s\ Y))$ of $\gamma(t)=exp_p(t\ X)$.

Our Professor gives us in the discussion the identity
$$||\frac{\partial v(s,t)}{\partial t}||_{g_{v(s,t)}}=||\frac{\partial v(s,t)}{\partial t}||_{g_{v(0,t)}}=||X+sY||_p$$

I see that $||\frac{\partial v(s,t)}{\partial t}||_{g_{v(s,t)}}=||X+sY||_p$, because $v$ is in $t$ direction a geodesic and the geodesic has to be unit speed (**Edit:** constant speed, not necessarily unit speed). So the velocity at $t$ equals the starting condition.

The step in the middle seems strange. Could somebody verify if the middle step is correct and why? Shouldn't $\frac{\partial v(s,t)}{\partial t}$ live at $T_{v(s,t)}M$.

Comment: This looks like a typo. The norm in the middle term should be evaluated at $g_v(s,0)$.

Comment: By the way, it's not true that a geodesic has to be unit speed. But it has to have constant speed.

Comment: That would make more sense, can you provide an counter example for the given statement?
I guess simple examples like the sphere, $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the hyperbolic space won't work because of local symmetry.
Yes, i'll edit the constant speed in! Sorry!

Comment: The middle term is independent of $s$, so the given statement is never going to be true unless $Y=0$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was so lost in my thoughts I just hoped something would come out of it :D Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some more background, and what textbook do you use I'm intersted

Comment: @Ezio We didn't use any textbook, this Profs lectures have always a discussion like touch. This discussion he later reused in the proof of [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)) with exactly that variation. And with Gauss's Lemma he went on to proof Hopf-Rinow.